# How can i configure a DNS server client communication between two linux machine?

Tags: domain-name-system

I need to configure a **simple** DNS server client communication between two linux machines.

I have the configuration files of bind9 but i didn't get much idea from that.

Can any one help on this?

My requirement is , when i type **nslookup www.google.com** **[my DNS server name**] in my client will yield the IP address of google.com

this can be done by editing the root.hint , but i dont know how.

/renjith g**strong text**

Comment: I think I'm a little lost on what a dns server client is.

Comment: Your DNS server should already look up the address if it doesn't have it from the root servers (or your machine's configured DNS server) if you have it set up as a caching server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-3.html

> A first stab at DNS config, very
>   useful for dialup, cable-modem, ADSL
>   and similar users.
>
> On Red Hat and Red Hat related
>   distributions you can achieve the same
>   practical result as this HOWTO's first
>   section by installing the packages
>   bind, bind-utils and
>   caching-nameserver. If you use Debian
>   simply install bind (or bind9, as of
>   this writing, BIND 9 is not supported
>   by Debian Stable (potato)) and
>   bind-doc. Of course just installing
>   those packages won't teach you as much
>   as reading this HOWTO. So install the
>   packages, and then read along
>   verifying the files they installed.

This screams "homework"..

Comment: Thanks Grizly.
It is working here in my linux machines.
Now i have given in client like nslookup www.google.com [my dns server name]  and i got reply from my DNS server as 209.85.231.104 , this because i have written my comapny DNS address in the root.hint of my local DNS server.

But i want to reply back one IP address from my local DNS server , that decision must be taken by this same local DNS server not my company DNS server unlike earlier.

How can i send an IP address curresponding to the query for www.google.com from client by just editing the root.hint of local server  ?

/renjith g

Comment: I *think* you are talking about "Forwarding".. https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/bind Unless you are talking about hosting your own "version" of the google.com domain. Please be clearer in your questions, as the Root Hints are only for resolving the Top Level Domains (.com .au .org etc) this has NOTHING to do with google.. if you host a domain called google.com, it will respond from your server with an ip you specify.. is that it? Do you want to know how to setup a domain in bind? Try this: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/dns-server-setup-using-bind-in-ubuntu.html